# Unpacking dataframe column with list values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say we have `df_orig` below with column `B` including lists of differing length as rows. In each row in `B`, the values of `X` are unique. Each unique value of `X` may or may not appear in each row of `B`. I think the example explains best.

```
import pandas as pd

df_orig = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    'B': [
        [{'X': 'abc'}],
        [{'X': 'abc'}, {'X': 'dtf'}, {'X': 'kju'}],
        [{'X': 'abc'}, {'X': 'dtf'}],
        [{'X': 'abc'}, {'X': 'dtf'}, {'X': 'kju'}, {'X': 'etr'}],
        []
    ] 
})

df_orig
    A   B
0   a   [{'X': 'abc'}]
1   b   [{'X': 'abc'}, {'X': 'dtf'}, {'X': 'kju'}]
2   c   [{'X': 'abc'}, {'X': 'dtf'}]
3   d   [{'X': 'abc'}, {'X': 'dtf'}, {'X': 'kju'}, {'X': 'etr'}]
4   e   []
```

What I want is to 'unpack' `B` so that each unique value of `X` gets its own column, with a `0/1` encoding indicating whether that value (the column name) was present in each row. The desired `dataframe`, `df_des`, would look like this:

```
df_des
    A   abc dtf kju etr
0   a   1   0   0   0
1   b   1   1   1   0
2   c   1   1   0   0
3   d   1   1   1   1
4   e   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dataframe constructor and return the values of the dictionary in each cell with `applymap` , the `get_dummies` and `join`:

```
m = (pd.DataFrame(df_orig['B'].tolist()).applymap(lambda x: 
                [*x.values()][0] if isinstance(x,dict) else x))
final = df_orig[['A']].join(
        pd.get_dummies(m).groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[-1],axis=1).max())
```

EDIT:
To join multiple columns you can [`pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) out the column `B` and join as shown below:

```
m = (pd.DataFrame(df_orig.pop('B').tolist()).applymap(lambda x: 
            [*x.values()][0] if isinstance(x,dict) else x))
final = df_orig.join(
    pd.get_dummies(m).groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[-1],axis=1).max())
```

---

```
   A  abc  dtf  etr  kju
0  a    1    0    0    0
1  b    1    1    0    1
2  c    1    1    0    0
3  d    1    1    1    1
4  e    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Your solution is very neat. I wonder if this somehow depends on `A`? The reason I ask is that in reality there are many columns apart from `A`, so ideally I just need to append the new columns to the original `df`.

Comment: @CHRD if there are many columns to join on I have edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach :

```
  #extract the data from the dictionary
  df_orig['C'] = df_orig.B.apply(lambda x: [i['X'] for i in x])
  #convert list to string
  df_orig.C = df_orig.C.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x))
  create dummies from split string
  dum = pd.get_dummies(df_orig.C.str.split(',', expand=True)).drop('0_',axis=1)
   #strip numbers off the columns
  dum.columns = dum.columns.str.replace('\d_','')
   #join dummies back to parent dataframe
  pd.concat([df_orig['A'], dum], axis=1).filter(['A','abc','dtf','etr','kju'])

        A   abc dtf etr kju
0       a   1   0   0   0
1       b   1   1   0   1
2       c   1   1   0   0
3       d   1   1   1   1
4       e   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

df_orig = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    'B': [
        [{'X': 'abc'}],
        [{'X': 'abc'}, {'X': 'dtf'}, {'X': 'kju'}],
        [{'X': 'abc'}, {'X': 'dtf'}],
        [{'X': 'abc'}, {'X': 'dtf'}, {'X': 'kju'}, {'X': 'etr'}],
        []
    ] 
})

b = []
for x in df_orig.B:
    dummy = []
    for y in x:
        dummy.append(y['X'])
    b.append(dummy)

b = pd.Series(b)

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
res = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(b),columns=mlb.classes_,index=b.index)
df_orig = df_orig.drop(['B'],axis=1)

df_res = pd.concat([df_orig,res],axis=1)
print(df_res)

output:
   A  abc  dtf  etr  kju
0  a    1    0    0    0
1  b    1    1    0    1
2  c    1    1    0    0
3  d    1    1    1    1
4  e    0    0    0    0
```

First, make B column to list of lists and then use multilabelbinarizer to one-hot encode the list of lists.